# Writing system in Ax=b form with variables x and y?

Tags: linear-algebra

A homework problem I have says to write the following system in **Ax=b** form:
\begin{cases}
\,\,\, x - 2y = 1\\
2x + 3y = 4
\end{cases}

Since the variables are x and y rather than x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>, what should I put for the x matrix?  x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> or x and y?

I.E. 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\ -2\\ 2\quad 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

Would that be correct?

Comment: Try to apply the matrice-vector multiplication and see if it gives what you want :)

Comment: I know it gives me what I want...But doesn't Ax=b form imply that the x matrix needs to be composed of, well, x variables? is it accurate to refer to something as "**x**" when it contains a y?

Comment: Write $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$, then $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)^T$

Comment: "is it accurate to refer to something as "x" when it contains a y?"  "x" and "y" are just arbitrary labels.  You can define/label things however you'd like.

Comment: [A rose by any other name would smell as sweet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Yes, that would be correct.

The problem here is, people have a habit of reusing the same symbols (e.g x, y, z) to express different things in different contexts, and so they sometimes reuse them to express more than one thing in the same context by accident (your teacher probably didn't even notice).  The important thing is to understand the role each letter is playing where it is used, rather than what specific letter it is; that way, you can avoid confusing different usages of the same letter.  For example, here the boldface **x** in the *general form* **Ax=b** has to be a vector, while the plainface x in the *specific equation set* must be a plain number, so they aren't 'the same x'.

A helpful trick: Start by replacing x and y in the equations with u and v, or other unused letters; then answer the question in terms of u and v; then back-substitute x and y in the answer.

Comment: Good answer. I believe professors should remark heavily these kind of things when first teaching this.